# How LSTM can be varying in length if I stack a fully connected layer top to it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I try to build a varying length LSTM. First, I make LSTM units then I stack a fully connected layer with 2 output nodes. The code is below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 5))) 
model.add(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))  

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam')

for episode in range(2):
    sequence_length = np.random.randint(10, 100)
    x_train = np.random.random((1000, sequence_length, 5))
    y_train = x_train[:, :, 0]
    for i in range(1, 5):
        y_train[:, i:] += x_train[:, :-i, i]
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train > 2.5)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, verbose=1)
```

But the problem is, I know LSTM can be varying in length, but when I stack fully connected layer top to it, how can it still be varying at length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: The `Dense` layer doesn't care about the size of anything except the last dimension, so it "just works", and is being applied to each time step independently.

Looking at the [LSTM docs](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/), it accepts only a 3D block of data shaped `[batch, timesteps, feature]`. Then it will iterate over the timesteps dimension, recurrently feeding the output as input for the next time step.

Looking at the [Dense docs](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/), it accepts any sized data. If there are more than 2 dimensions to your data, it will simply apply the layer independently across each of the intermediate dimensions.

That is, if you give a `Dense` layer an input shaped `[batch, timestep, feature_in]`, it will vectorise the operation over both the `batch` and `timestep` dimension, giving you back an output shaped `[batch, timestep, feature_out]`. You can think of this as doing something like:

```py
out = [dense_layer(inp[:, s]) for s in range(inp.shape[1])]
```

It should be noted that `feature_in` and `feature_out` in this description is determined when you create your model, not when you give it an example.

E.g. Let's say I make a dense layer which takes a vector with 2 values and creates a vector with 3 values. Then it doesn't matter how many dimensions the input has, the layer will take the last dimension as the vector, and apply the same operation across all of the other dimensions

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, input_shape=(2,))

inp1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random((4, 2)).astype(np.float32))
# <tf.Tensor 'Const:0' shape=(4, 2) dtype=float32>
out1 = dense_layer(inp1)
# <tf.Tensor 'dense/BiasAdd:0' shape=(4, 3) dtype=float32>

inp2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random((5, 4, 2)).astype(np.float32))
# <tf.Tensor 'Const_1:0' shape=(5, 4, 2) dtype=float32>
out3 = dense_layer(inp2)
# <tf.Tensor 'dense/BiasAdd_1:0' shape=(5, 4, 3) dtype=float32>

inp3 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random((6, 5, 4, 2)).astype(np.float32))
# <tf.Tensor 'Const_2:0' shape=(6, 5, 4, 2) dtype=float32>
out3 = dense_layer(inp3)
# <tf.Tensor 'dense/BiasAdd_2:0' shape=(6, 5, 4, 3) dtype=float32>

inp4 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random((7, 6, 5, 4, 2)).astype(np.float32))
# <tf.Tensor 'Const_5:0' shape=(7, 6, 5, 4, 2) dtype=float32>
out4 = dense_layer(inp4)
# <tf.Tensor 'dense/BiasAdd_5:0' shape=(7, 6, 5, 4, 3) dtype=float32>

inp5 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random((8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2)).astype(np.float32))
# <tf.Tensor 'Const_6:0' shape=(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2) dtype=float32>
out5 = dense_layer(inp5)
# <tf.Tensor 'dense/BiasAdd_6:0' shape=(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3) dtype=float32>
```

Comment: @Mutihunter  you said, "It's being applied to each time step independently." how can dense layer be applied in each timestep or you are trying to say that, the dense layer is only connected with the last timestep's output vector.

Comment: In precisely the same way that it is applied over all elements of the batch independently. I'm talking in terms of the mathematical operation, not in some abstract "connectedness". I'll update the answer with an example.